# cannot resolve AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calcKappa'

Tags: python

I'm completely new to python. Now i'm using Enthought canopy (python 2.7.3).
I know this question has been asked a million times before and i can imagine you all are tired of this question but it has been bugging me all day.

```
import Basismodel

def doAll(c):
   #from Basismodel import calcKappa
   Basismodel.setC(c)
   Basismodel.setMu()
   Basismodel.setLambda()
   Basismodel.calcKappa()
   Basismodel.calcSumofprob()
   Basismodel.calcPi()

doAll(100)
```

With another file Basismodel.py where all functions mentioned in here are defined.
It doesn't give any error with the first 3 but it does with the last 3.

As extra information I'll give you the code for Basismodel.py as well

```
global c
global lamb
global pi
global kappa
global mu
global sumofkappa
global f
f=0.6 #the percentage that takes the car
c=100 #max
sumofkappa=0 #sum of all kappa
sumofpi=0 #sum of all probabilities (should be equal to 1)
pi=[]
kappa=[1.0]
mu=[0.4]
lamb=[0.1] #Lambda is de arrival rate

def setC(y):
    c=y
    #print c

def setMu():
    global mu
    for i in range (c):
        mu.append((i+2)*mu[0])
        #print mu[i]

def setLambda():

    for i in range (c):
        lamb.append(lamb[1])
        #print lamb[i]

def calcKappa():

    for i in range (c):
        if (i==0):
            kappa[0]=1.0
        else:
            kappa[i].append(kappa[i-1]*lamb[i-1]/mu[i])

def calcSumofprob():
    for i in range (c):
        global sumofkappa
        sumofkappa += kappa[i]

def calcPi():
    for i in range (c):
        pi.append(kappa[i]/sumofkappa)

def calcAveragePi():
    for i in range(c):
        global sumofpi
        sumofpi += pi[i]
    return sumofpi/c
```

When I execute the main it gives this error, it doesn't make any sense since all print lines are in #comment style. 
However I am more interested in why it can't find the attribute. Also when i set "#from .Basismodel import calcKappa" after def doAll, the error changes to an importerror where it can't import.

```
%run "C:/Users/Thomas/Dropbox/Thesis/Canopy files/Main.py"
100
0.4
0.8
1.2
1.6
2.0
2.4
2.8
3.2
3.6
4.0
4.4
4.8
5.2
5.6
6.0
6.4
6.8
7.2
7.6
8.0
8.4
0.8
1.2
1.6
2.0
2.4
2.8
3.2
3.6
4.0
4.4
4.8
5.2
5.6
6.0
6.4
6.8
7.2
7.6
8.0
8.4
0.8
1.2
1.6
2.0
2.4
2.8
3.2
3.6
4.0
4.4
4.8
5.2
5.6
6.0
6.4
6.8
7.2
7.6
8.0
8.4
0.8
1.2
1.6
2.0
2.4
2.8
3.2
3.6
4.0
4.4
4.8
5.2
5.6
6.0
6.4
6.8
7.2
7.6
8.0
8.4
0.8
1.2
1.6
2.0
2.4
2.8
3.2
3.6
4.0
4.4
4.8
5.2
5.6
6.0
6.4
6.8
7.2
7.6
8.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\Thomas\Dropbox\Thesis\Canopy files\Main.py in <module>()
    17     return Basismodel.calcAveragePi()
    18 
---> 19 doAll(100)
    20 
    21 #while(condition==0):

C:\Users\Thomas\Dropbox\Thesis\Canopy files\Main.py in doAll(c)
    12     Basismodel.setMu()
    13     Basismodel.setLambda()
---> 14     Basismodel.calcKappa()
    15     Basismodel.calcSumofprob()
    16     Basismodel.calcPi()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calcKappa'
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Try making the most simple example you can, i.e. a `main.py` that contains only `import basismodel; basismodel.calc_kappa()` and a `basismodel.py` that contains only `def calc_kappa(): pass`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
global c
global lamb
global pi
global kappa
global mu
global sumofkappa
global f
```

Those lines don't do what you think they do. `global` is a keyword that is place within a function to reference the global declaration of a variable.

e.g.

```
x = 42
def without_global():
    x = 9
    print(x)

def with_global():
    global x
    x = 13
    print(x)

print(x)
without_global()
print(x)
with_global()
print(x)
```

I get entirely different issues here, though.

Comment: thank you for respnding, the problem is that if i manage to fix something, i get another error, which is probably perfectly normal. But when I save and close canopy, reopen it and run it again I get a different error. Most of the times still an attribute error but then from a piece of code that is executed later. This means I'm improving but I don't know why.

Comment: It sounds like canopy is giving you problems - I would run your script from the command line, if at all possible. You likely need to work the other way around - rather than writing a huge chunk of code (e.g. the whole program), write a smaller chunk - perhaps one function. When that function works, then add another, and so on until you have an entire program that works. Fixing an error and then getting another error is **not** what I would consider normal.