# Self repeating error

Tags: python

I'm completely new to python. Now i'm using Enthought canopy (python 2.7.3). I posted a question on line but then I got to another question.
I wrote a program and of course ran into errors. I posted this also on this forum.
Here is the link to my previous question: [cannot resolve AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calcKappa'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389460/cannot-resolve-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-calckappa)
I saw that when I removed the print lines, canopy kept printing these output long after I removed these lines and saved my data.
So I rebooted the editor and now, all of the sudden I have other errors.
So I added some print lines to test it, and now the program got stuck on the print line.
Why is that?

```
     %run "C:/Users/User/Canopy files/Main.py"
5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\User\Canopy files\Main.py in <module>()
    22     cTwo*=2
    23     cOne*=2
---> 24     averagepiTwo=doAll(cTwo)
    25     averagepiOne=doAll(cOne)
    26     if(averagepiTwo >= averagepiOne*(1-criterium)):

C:\Users\User\Canopy files\Main.py in doAll(c)
    12     Basismodel.setMu()
    13     print 5
---> 14     Basismodel.setLambda()
    15     Basismodel.calcKappa()
    16     Basismodel.calcSumofprob()

C:\Users\User\Canopy files\Basismodel.py in setLambda()
    25 
    26 def setLambda():
---> 27     print "test"
    28     for i in range (c-1):
    29         lamb.append(lamb[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

thank you in advance.

**The answer was that I didn't have a constructor.
Thank you for your responses**

Comment: You need to check out http://sscce.org/ and post an SSCCE.

Answer (score 2):

First, delete the `*.pyc` files in the `Canopy files` directory. The interpreter should recompile the python `.py` file to a `.pyc` everytime but there are some edge cases where old `.pyc` are not replaced and you will get a traceback where the line throwing the exception does not correspond to the actual line throwing the exception. In short, the exception traceback shows the updated `.py` content, not the executed one.

Second, the exception is most likely coming from the statement `lamb[0]`. Are you sure the `lamb` list have values before calling `setLambda()`? Perhaps you meant `i` instead of `lamb[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error could be in the last line:

```
29 lamb.append(lamb[0])
```

It seems to append the first element of the list lamb to lamb itself. Is that what you want to do? Have you defined lamb[0] before append it to lamb? Before answering too fast to the last question, think about if lamb is defined outside the function setLambda(). If it is the case, then lamb should be defined as global variable. Otherwise it doesn't exist any variable lamb inside the frame of the selLambda() function.

Answer (score 0):

it will probably change later but for now it just needs to copy the first value over the rest of the list.
The module basismodel starts with this code:

```
f=0.6 #the percentage that takes the car
c=100 #max
sumofkappa=0 #sum of all kappa
sumofpi=0 #sum of all probabilities (should be equal to 1)
pi=[]
kappa=[1.0]
mu=[0.4]
lamb=[0.1] #Lambda is de arrival rate
```